# Desgining a Restful service

Tags: web-services, rest, restful-url, restful-architecture

Lets say I am designing a Restful service which given 2 integer no.'s returns the sum of it.
In this case there is no resource to be read, created, updated or deleted. 
So, if I design something like GET /sum/first/33/second/44, it doesn't comply with the REST standards as **'sum'** is a verb and instead there should be a noun representing the resource name.
So, how should the API call look like for invoking the sum.

Please help me with the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST says nothing about what your URLs should look like. You can honestly have anything you want: `GET /hdueqixp` returning "77", for example.

Me, I like short, self-explanitory URIs. I would use `/sum/33+44`. You're not including action parameters in the request URL, so don't worry about verbs vs. nouns. That is for people still doing things like `GET /users/deepak?action=delete` and expecing the resource to be deleted.

Comment: @DeepakGarg Actually, I just realised, the word `sum` is redundant if you include a plus in the URL, and it is defined by your API to mean summation. You could just as easily have `/33+44` or `/result/33+44`

Answer (score 5):

Use "summation" instead of "sum" if your concern is noun vs. verb.  As far as parameters are concerned, I think you should supply all the numbers you want to sum up together for eg. /summation/1,2,3,4 or /summation/1+2+3+4.

Comment: Thanks, but "summation" is still not a resource.

Comment: Is "sum" a resource you've already defined?  I think that summation should be an action and not a resource.  You could define something like /numbers/1,2,3,4/summation where summation would be an action where you would parse the supplied parameters "1,2,3,4", add them and return the result.

Comment: I am not sure if **/numbers/1,2,3,4/summation** complies with the REST architecture

Comment: Deepak, you could pass parameters in query string, eg. /numbers/summation?num=1,2,3,4.  If a comma separated numbers is something you do not want to use then you could do /numbers/summation?firstNum=1&secondNum=2&thirdNum=3&forthNum=4 and so on.  To make this prettier your url can be rewritten as /numbers/summation/1/2/3/4.  In my previous example i.e. /numbers/1,2,3,4/summation, I meant to say /numbers/:listOfNumbers/summation where :listOfNumbers would hold the numbers to be added(of course it does not look pretty), why do you say does not comply with REST architecture?

Comment: @DeepakGarg BTW: "sum" is just a contraction of "summation" and both words are both nouns and verbs, the noun representing the result of applying the verb. Like "I am doing the washing". The washing, in this case, is a noun.